# Extract in which sequence a loop created an error

Tags: r

I have a loop to test different values in a function. I would like to know which of the values causes a problem for later examination. So i would like to save the round and then the loop to continue.
I create some dummy data and an empty vector to save the loop round:

```
stuff <- c(12, 9, 2, "cat", 25, 10, "horse")
troublemaker <- c()
```

And now the loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(stuff)) {
  print(i)
  tryCatch(expr = print(log(stuff[[i]])),
           error = function(e) {
             message('An Error Occurred!!!');
             troublemaker <- c(troublemaker, i)
           }
  )
}
```

I saw this in different examples, but those didn't work for me. I reinstalled even R. So, `troublemaker` should contain 4 and 7 at the end, but it is as empty as before. Is this not working, because `troublemaker <- c(troublemaker, i)`is within that function? I also tried `error = troublemaker <- c(troublemaker, i)`, but then it counts every round.
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Your example is poor - a vector can only have one data type so when you mix numerics and strings in a vector they are all coerced to string. `log(stuff[1])` throws an error.

Comment: If you replace `c` with `list` in the `stuff` definition, it will work. (And your code already uses `[[` which is needed for `list` extraction.) Though that's not your only issue - `troublemaker` will still be empty. If you saw this "in many examples", perhaps you could link to one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in R, expressions evaluated inside functions are local to those functions. `function(e) troublemaker <- c(troublemaker, i)` will modify `troublemaker` in the context of the anonymous function, but it will not modify `troublemaker` in your global environment.

Though usually (and rightly) frowned upon, this is a case where global assignment `<<-` may make sense. (Note that I've also changed your `stuff` vector to a `list` as mentioned in comments.)

```
stuff <- list(12, 9, 2, "cat", 25, 10, "horse")
troublemaker <- c()

for (i in 1:length(stuff)) {
  print(i)
  tryCatch(expr = print(log(stuff[[i]])),
           error = function(e) {
             message('An Error Occurred!!!');
             troublemaker <<- c(troublemaker, i)
           }
  )
}
# [1] 1
# [1] 2.484907
# [1] 2
# [1] 2.197225
# [1] 3
# [1] 0.6931472
# [1] 4
# An Error Occurred!!!
# [1] 5
# [1] 3.218876
# [1] 6
# [1] 2.302585
# [1] 7
# An Error Occurred!!!
troublemaker
# [1] 4 7
```